# How to remove or set form input background-color in chrome?

Tags: css, browser

I add this style into my scss file:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
  background-color: $background-white !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0px 1000px $background-white inset !important;
}
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  background-color: $background-white !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px $background-white inset !important;
}
```

but it didn't work, and I don't want to set my form autocomplete to off.Is there another way for this problem?

Comment: My style write in other file to override purecss style work,it override the -webkit-box-shadow value;

Comment: In fact, what I need just this line:-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px $background-white inset !important;